# Http to Https POST

Tags: http, post, https

We are launching a new website(say A) and it has Username/Password to it and ours is a HTTP Site. We are POSTING Username/Password  information to another site which is our another internal website(Say B) but that website is HTTPS site.  Our 'A' site don’t handle Authorization and Authentication and neither we have Data bases nor their going to be any back communications(for error handling stuff like that) to the 'B' From 'A'. we tranfer them to the B website altogether and no coming back.

My Question is

Is the information I am Posting from HTTP to HTTPS site is secure? If yes How its secure. If No why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data will be encrypted from the browser to website B, *but* the end-user has no assurance that website B is who it claims to be. A "man in the middle" attack could be used which would deliver the secure information to the phony site.

Therefore, your login page should be hosted on website B and delivered using SSL (https).

Comment: Say Suppose a middle man come into picture and redirects Encrypted information to phony site. is it possble to decrypt the information he redirected? Also How is he does the redirect to a phony site?

Comment: The idea is that a "man in the middle" (proxy) could intercept the unencrypted http page and change the form's POST destination to the phony site. Therefore when the sensitive data is sent, it is encrypted with the phony key and delivered to the phony site, where it is decrypted. Is this likely to happen? Not really, but it is possible, so the scenario you describe can not be considered completely secure unless you have complete control of the network you are using (e.g. a segregated intranet).

Comment: I'm not sure this means anything. You can POST to any "phony site" from a "secure" https site too.

Comment: I'm not sure your comment means anything to me. Please elaborate.

Comment: The other part of a "secure" site is using a trusted certificate. If the https site has a cert and is from a trusted CA, why would it try to post to a "phony site"?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the user can verify the absence of scripts running on site A, it's possible to ensure that it's secure. What makes it a generally bad practice is that it's vulnerable to an active man in the middle who changes the form target or inserts a malicious script in the context of site A to steal the password and send it away before it gets submitted to the (secure) site B.

Comment: A script is not needed to steal the data. A proxy can change the destination of the form POST. See my other comment.

Comment: @Ray Henry: There are 2 ways the proxy could grab the data: either changing the action URL of the form (which is detectable easily by viewing source), or by using client-side scripting. What I meant by the absence of scripts is that if you know there isn't any scripting there, then you can just check the action of the form to see where the data's going to go

Comment: An end user is not likely to look at the source of a page to see if there are scripts or that the form POST destination is not phony. I stand by my answer that the login page (containing the form) should be delivered by https, which will show the user that the page is secured and that the host is known and trusted.

Comment: Oh I totally agree that it should be delivered over HTTPS. I'll often click "Log in" on HTTP login pages just to get delivered to the HTTPS site before actually entering credentials.